# Unexpected results using WITH ROLLUP + HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This query comes from "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Database Development" (page 26 if you have the book).  And, since the query was found in this book, I am running against the AdventureWorks2008 database.  The question arises by the first query posted, however there is a second query below with a workaround.

Question: Why are we missing a subtotal row for ProductCategoryID = 2, as well as a grand total row on the following query when using WITH ROLLUP along with the HAVING clause?

All ProductCategoryID's have a subtotal row and a grand total row is included in the result set when removing the HAVING clause.

Query:

```
SELECT
    Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID
    , Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
    , AVG(ListPrice) AS 'Average'
    , MIN(ListPrice) AS 'Minimum'
    , MAX(ListPrice) AS 'Maximum'
FROM Production.Product
JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory ON Production.ProductSubcategory.ProductSubcategoryID = Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
JOIN Production.ProductCategory ON Production.ProductSubcategory.ProductCategoryID = Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID
WHERE
    ListPrice <> 0
GROUP BY
    Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID
    , Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
    MIN(ListPrice) > 200
```

Results:

```
ProductCategoryId   ProductSubcategoryId    Average     Minimum Maximum
1                   1                       1683.365    539.99  3399.99
1                   2                       1597.45     539.99  3578.27
1                   3                       1425.2481   742.35  2384.07
1                   NULL                    1586.737    539.99  3578.27
2                   12                      678.2535    249.79  1364.50
2                   14                      780.0436    337.22  1431.50
2                   16                      631.4155    333.42  1003.91
```

---

Query that concludes in the results I expected to see in the original query (problem is solved by replacing our HAVING clause with a subquery):

```
SELECT
    Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID
    , Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
    , AVG(ListPrice) AS 'Average'
    , MIN(ListPrice) AS 'Minimum'
    , MAX(ListPrice) AS 'Maximum'
FROM Production.Product
JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory ON Production.ProductSubcategory.ProductSubcategoryID = Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
JOIN Production.ProductCategory ON Production.ProductSubcategory.ProductCategoryID = Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID
WHERE
    ListPrice <> 0
    AND Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID IN 
    (
        SELECT
            Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
        FROM Production.Product
        GROUP BY
            Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
        HAVING
            MIN(ListPrice) > 200
    )
GROUP BY
    Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID
    , Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
WITH ROLLUP
```

Results:

```
ProductCategoryId   ProductSubcategoryId    Average     Minimum Maximum
1                   1                       1683.365    539.99  3399.99
1                   2                       1597.45     539.99  3578.27
1                   3                       1425.2481   742.35  2384.07
1                   NULL                    1586.737    539.99  3578.27
2                   12                      678.2535    249.79  1364.50
2                   14                      780.0436    337.22  1431.50
2                   16                      631.4155    333.42  1003.91
2                   NULL                    710.1015    249.79  1431.50
NULL                NULL                    1193.2472   249.79  3578.27
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "Those rows are missing because the HAVING clause is applied after the ROLLUP clause".
One way to get the rows back is to change the HAVING clause from:

```
HAVING
     MIN(ListPrice) > 200
```

to:

```
HAVING
     (MIN(ListPrice) > 200)
  or (Grouping (Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID) = 1)
  or (Grouping (Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID) =  1)
```

Also, there should be an order clause. Something like:

```
Order by Case
            When (Grouping (Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID) = 1) Then 1
            Else 0
            End,
         Production.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID,
         Case
            When (Grouping (Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID) =  1) Then 1
            Else 0
            End,
         Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

Those rows are missing because the HAVING clause is applied after the ROLLUP clause and MIN(ListPrice) is less than 200 for those rows (it is 20.24 for the total of <strike>ProductSubcategoryId</strike> ProductCategoryId 2 and 2.29 for the grand total).

To get the same results as your second query, you could also use:

```
SELECT
    c.ProductCategoryID
    , s.ProductSubcategoryID
    , AVG(ListPrice) AS 'Average'
    , MIN(ListPrice) AS 'Minimum'
    , MAX(ListPrice) AS 'Maximum'
FROM (
    SELECT *, MIN(ListPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductSubcategoryID) AS MinimumListPriceForSubcategory
    FROM Production.Product
) p
JOIN Production.ProductSubcategory s ON s.ProductSubcategoryID = p.ProductSubcategoryID
JOIN Production.ProductCategory c ON s.ProductCategoryID = c.ProductCategoryID
WHERE ListPrice <> 0
AND MinimumListPriceForSubcategory>200
GROUP BY c.ProductCategoryID, s.ProductSubcategoryID
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: The min list price is not less than 200 for those rows.  The second query above is against the same data, check out the min list price on those records.

Comment: If you remove the HAVING clause from the first query, you can see that MIN(ListPrice) for the entire ProductCategoryId=2 is 20.24, being the minimum value for ProductSubcategoryId=7. As I wrote above, the ROLLUP clause is applied before the HAVING clause, therefore it calculates the minimum value for all subcategories in a category (including those that are later excluded by the HAVING clause).